# add conditional color on maps using geom_polygon

Tags: r, polygon, ggmap

I want to add borders to differentiate the broader 4 regions on the map created by using geom_polygon. Is there a way of doing it? right now i'm only able to add dots on the intersecting border. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a way to identify those borders you want different?

Comment: the basic idea is to add borders or bold borders between regions, not between states.

Comment: Add a column to your shape data identifying the edges you want to highlight and it shouldn't be too hard from there.

Comment: yes I have identified the data for the positions of the borders, but have no clue how to condition the geom_polygon border on those.

Comment: this is the my code right now, edge_color is binary indicating the points where I want to highlight, but it wouldn't produce the output I want (the data is correct)  ggplot()+ geom_polygon(data=map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group,                 fill=rate,colour=edge_color)

Comment: Please edit the code into your question - it's very hard to read in the comments. Also mention the name of the column you added to your data indicating the borders you want highlighted. Showing the `head` of your data might be nice too.